# How to load and show comments with AJAX instead of pagination?

Tags: comments, ajax, php

Is there a plugin that displays comments like this:

http://img541.imageshack.us/img541/6541/47905634.jpg

when the user clicks "read more", older comments are being appended to the list with ajax.

Comment: [It looks you created a nice solution yourself](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/4567/getting-comments-outside-the-comment-template). If you post it here as an answer, future visitors can benefit from it too.

Comment: I will when I'll have a working solution :)

Comment: Now that the Community User bumped this question: did you manage to solve your problem?

Comment: The image is broken. I have some idea how to implement that easily, let me know if you're still interested.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like Lester Chan has created a plugin that creates pagination for comments. Take a look at [WP-CommentNavi 1.10](http://lesterchan.net/portfolio/programming/php)

Lester Chan has created many good plugins.

Comment: Question is about how to use AJAX for this. Comment pagination is native WP functionality for a while already and doesn't require a plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this question is very old (8 years!!!) but still has no answer!

I will publish a small solution for future visitors.

Implementing load more button for comments is much simpler than for posts, you just need to

1. Create a button if comment pages are 2 and more
2. Create a jQuery script that will process the button click event and passes the current comment page number to `wp_ajax_` action hook
3. The last step – is `wp_ajax_` function that will process the AJAX request.

That's all!

But if you need the ready code, please look at this tutorial https://rudrastyh.com/wordpress/load-more-comments.html

Answer (score -1):

Its batter if you get plugins for that, but if dont find that then its not difficult to develop Customize functionality. You can find too many help for that, And its also easy by using Jquery..

You can also refer this link http://plugins.learningjquery.com/expander/demo/index.html

Just want to suggest you.

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

The ajax comment loading plugin can be useful for this too. That one will load comments according to Google specification so it is good for when the google bot crawls your comments.

The original one developed by Mark Jaquith is currently broken but this one will do the job:
http://www.tipsandtricks-hq.com/ajax-comment-loading-plugin-fixed-6096