# Getting $comments outside the comment template

Tags: customization, comments, php, ajax

I have a ajax request hooked on "template_redirect" (the ajax requests the post's url), and I want to display only the comment template:

```
function get_comm(){
  if(isset($_GET['get_my_comments'])):
    $offset = intval($_GET['get_my_comments']);
    echo $offset; // offset will be the same as "cpage"
    global $comments, $wp_query, $post, $id;
    print_r($comments); // nothing ?
    print_r($wp_query->comments); // nothing ??
    wp_list_comments('type=comment', $comments); // same :(
    exit();
  endif;
}
add_action('template_redirect', 'get_comm');
```

the javascript part works and it's like this:

```
   $("a.show-more-comments").live("click", function(){
      var offset = $(this).attr('rel');
      var list = $(this).closest("#comments");

      $.ajax({
        url: "<?php echo get_permalink($post->ID); ?>",
        type: "GET",
        data: ({
          get_my_comments: offset
        }),
        success: function(data){
          list.append(data);
        }
      });
    });
```

The problem is that `$comments` or `$wp_query->comments` don't seem to be initialized. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Why don't you use redirect? Why not simply reload the page if you want to load the comment template to show more comments? Or do you want to expand the list of comments on the same page?

Comment: yes, more comments should be retrieved and appended when a link is pressed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$comments`, or `$wp_query->comments`, is initialized by `comments_template()`, which you call in your template file when you want to load the comment sub-template file. So at the time of `template_redirect` it is not yet initialized. As Chris said, you should call `get_comments()` and pass it the `post_id` of your current post.

If you're doing AJAX calls, even not from the admin side, [you can use `wp-admin/admin-ajax.php` and use special actions hooks](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/3610/how-to-manage-ajax-calls-and-json-in-wordpress/3612#3612). This shortcuts the usual post queries, which you don't need anyway.

Comment: what's the difference between using `admin-ajax.php` and usual site url?

Comment: @Alex: Depending on the URL you currently use, WP will launch some queries before you reach `template_redirect`. If you use the regular post URL and then append your `get_my_comments`, it will still parse the URL according to the rewrite rules and get the post from the database, even if you don't use it later. The regular AJAX methods prevent this, they go straight to your function. But maybe you need the post anyway for the comment formatting?

Answer (score 0):

I use this function to render templates when using ajax

```
function ajax_render( $template ) {

global $data, $posts, $post, $wp_did_header, $wp_did_template_redirect, $wp_query, $wp_rewrite, $wpdb, $wp_version, $wp, $id, $comment,  $user_ID;

ob_start();
render($template);
$response = array('text' => ob_get_clean());
echo json_encode($response);
exit;
}
```

render() is a custom function to load a certain template. But essentially you will need to retrieve the comments yourself to add to the list.

Use get_comments (http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_comments) or do a direct query and then you can either render a template as above or build the html with a php function.

I use the global $data to hod anything I want to render in the template.

Comment: yes, I've come down to using `get_comments()` after all. The inconvenient is that now I have to use it on the first page load too, not only on the ajax call...