# Fastest way to get the comment and ping total count for a post

Tags: customization, comments, php, database, wp-query

I'm making my own comment template ([like this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/4580/prevent-wordpress-from-loading-comments)) and I need to know how can I get the comment and ping count for the current post, maybe using a fast database query or something like that?

Note that I can't use `count($comments)` or anything like that, because I'm not running the default `comments_template()` function which gets all the comments from the database. Instead I'm pulling only the newest 10 comments using `get_comments()`.

`$post->comment_count` (apparently initialized by [get_post](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post)) is close to what I'm looking for, but it counts both comments and pings :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use this custom function in the functions.php of the theme:

```
/**
 * count for trackback, pingback, comment, pings
 *
 * embed like this:
 * fb_comment_type_count('pings');
 * fb_comment_type_count('comment');
 */
if ( !function_exists('fb_comment_type_count') ) {
        function fb_get_comment_type_count( $type='all', $zero = false, $one = false, $more = false, $post_id = 0) {
                global $cjd_comment_count_cache, $id, $post;

                if ( !$post_id )
                        $post_id = $post->ID;
                if ( !$post_id )
                        return;

                if ( !isset($cjd_comment_count_cache[$post_id]) ) {
                        $p = get_post($post_id);
                        $p = array($p);
                        fb_update_comment_type_cache($p);
                }
                ;
                if ( $type == 'pingback' || $type == 'trackback' || $type == 'comment' )
                        $count = $cjd_comment_count_cache[$post_id][$type];
                elseif ( $type == 'pings' )
                        $count = $cjd_comment_count_cache[$post_id]['pingback'] + $cjd_comment_count_cache[$post_id]['trackback'];
                else
                        $count = array_sum((array) $cjd_comment_count_cache[$post_id]);

                return apply_filters('fb_get_comment_type_count', $count);
        }

        // comment, trackback, pingback, pings, all
        function fb_comment_type_count( $type='all', $zero = false, $one = false, $more = false, $post_id = 0 ) {

                $number = fb_get_comment_type_count( $type, $zero, $one, $more, $post_id );
                if ($type == 'all') {
                        $type_string_single = __('Kommentar', FB_BASIS_TEXTDOMAIN);
                        $type_string_plural = __('Kommentare', FB_BASIS_TEXTDOMAIN);
                } elseif ($type == 'pings') {
                        $type_string_single = __('Ping und Trackback', FB_BASIS_TEXTDOMAIN);
                        $type_string_plural = __('Pings und Trackbacks', FB_BASIS_TEXTDOMAIN);
                } elseif ($type == 'pingback') {
                        $type_string_single = __('Pingback', FB_BASIS_TEXTDOMAIN);
                        $type_string_plural = __('Pingbacks', FB_BASIS_TEXTDOMAIN);
                } elseif ($type == 'trackback') {
                        $type_string_single = __('Trackback', FB_BASIS_TEXTDOMAIN);
                        $type_string_plural = __('Trackbacks', FB_BASIS_TEXTDOMAIN);
                } elseif ($type == 'comment') {
                        $type_string_single = __('Kommentar', FB_BASIS_TEXTDOMAIN);
                        $type_string_plural = __('Kommentare', FB_BASIS_TEXTDOMAIN);
                }

                if ( $number > 1 )
                        $output = str_replace('%', number_format_i18n($number), ( false === $more ) ? __('%', FB_BASIS_TEXTDOMAIN) . ' ' . $type_string_plural : $more);
                elseif ( $number == 0 )
                        $output = ( false === $zero ) ? __('Keine', FB_BASIS_TEXTDOMAIN) . ' ' . $type_string_plural : $zero;
                else // must be one
                        $output = ( false === $one ) ? __('Ein', FB_BASIS_TEXTDOMAIN) . ' ' . $type_string_single : $one;

                echo apply_filters('fb_comment_type_count', $output, $number);
        }
}
```

this function give you the count of pingback, trackback, comments or all, example:

```
<h2 class="comments"><?php fb_comment_type_count( 'comment' ); ?></h2>
```

you can use the follow parameter for return the counter: comment, trackback, pingback, pings or all

Comment: that doesn't work. you have calls to some weird functions there, which are not available in wp..

Comment: sorry, i dont fint a call; but maybe you can meore read on the svn with all examples in my free WPBasis Theme: http://code.google.com/p/wp-basis-theme/source/browse/trunk/basis/functions.php?r=184
Is also available in html5